# Keeping symbol from stretching to patch size

Tags: arcgis-pro, symbology, legend, stretch

How is a symbol shape maintained without stretching to the patch size?

Attached images are legends in ArcMap and ArcGIS Pro to illustrate difference.  In ArcGIS Pro, the symbol shape looks good in the layer in Contents, but in the Legend it is stretched to the patch size.  Changing the patch size shifts the text of those legend items to the left, out of alignment with other text in the legend, because the patch is left-aligned.  Shrinking all the patch sizes so the symbol shapes are not distorted reduces the line symbols, which makes dashing and doting in line symbols difficult to discern.

A workaround that requires turning the legend into graphics is unsuitable since it will not be dynamic.

I am using ArcGIS Pro 3.0

[image: ArcMap legend]

[image: ArcGIS Pro legend]

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to change the default patch width.

[image: Solution]

Comment: I had tried this (noted in original post), but not a good fix.  If all patch sizes are reduced then any line symbology becomes difficult to discern.  If only specific patch sizes are changed to undistort the symbology then the text for those symbols in the legend shift left to be out of alignment with other text in the legend.

Comment: That can be easily resolved by you selecting the layer in the legend in TOC and then choosing labels in the elements panel then Position then Offset X. So it is a good fix.

Comment: Which leaves selected symbology left justified rather than all neatly center justified.  This is a compounding of workarounds rather than a solution to distorted symbology.

Comment: Well I tried to help, point you into the appropriate rabbit hole of symbology settings. Seems like you need to write a letter of complaint to ESRI or explore the legend settings further.

Comment: @TerryR. Can't you rather change the patch height to restore the symbol proportion without messing with the alignement ? (this shouldn't have any impact on line symbol but increasing the vertical distance between item)